# How to find out who the script owner is?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've built a Google App Script web app and I need to find out who the script owner is?

I want to disable the app, but it's telling me that I'm not the script owner. However I did create the script.

Comment: I'm not sure if this feature is available in Apps Script. One work around is to remove it in the list of [services connected to your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2541991?hl=en). This will stop working (permission denied) the app to access your account. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use class file

```
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("your app");
//search the correct file in the array
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file..getOwner());
 }
```

Comment: This was a useful answer and helped me find a solution. Thanks baptiste-gavalda.

Comment: @Berni You're welcome. You should probably share your solution for those who still didn't find the answer.